# div element is not visible on print page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table. Above the table, I create a horizontal line. When I click on the print button, the whole page is showing except the lines. The lines are generated as follows:

```js
$attachLinesTo = $('#dataset-wrap')

function createLine(x1, y1, l, colorClass) {
  return $('<div>')
    .appendTo($attachLinesTo)
    .addClass('line ' + colorClass)
    .css({
      position: 'absolute',
    })
    .width(l)
    .offset({
      left: x1,
      top: y1
    });
}
```

In the normal view (without printing) the page is showing everything correct. Only on the print page, the lines are missing.

I want to show the lines in the print view.

Here the css:

```css
.line {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: The javascript in this isn't important, the CSS is important. Does the div have a background or does it have a border and that is where the lines are coming from?

Comment: When are you calling the `createLine` function?

Comment: It seems to me like you are using a DIV when you should be using a Canvas (https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp)

Comment: create line function is called in the document ready function

Comment: What about `border-bottom: 1px solid black` ?

Comment: Maybe my problem is that the div with the line is above (overlaying) on a table. Could that be a problem for printing?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but FYI... When creating a new element, set up all the configurations on the element before appending it to the DOM so that users don't potentially see the element and then see its style change.

Answer (score 1):

By default, your browser doesn't print background colors.

You have to either enable background printing in your browser, or just use a border-top (or border-bottom) that is 1px and that should work.

```css
.line {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.black {
  border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="line black"></div>
```

Comment: I changed the code as above. Results are the same. The line is not visible on printing.

Comment: Have you changed all the color classes?